# How to find element of specific values in vector of doubles

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors, one of 8 double numbers, another of 1000.  Assigning the 10 numbers as follows

```
myDBL <- c(0.7644957248, -0.6612336692, -0.3755620978, -0.3715304872, -0.0759778128,  0.7515847845, -0.5997805210,  0.7625898273)
```

When I search for a specific double:

```
which(myDBL== -0.3755620978)
```

this return location 3.  Good, since that location evaluates to true.

So when I search the vector with 1000 double variables, I get 
integer(0)

I know the double I'm looking for is in the 2nd vector.  Why is "which" not finding it?

Using str(), both vectors report the same, except for length. (one is 8, the other is 1000).  I've also ensured both vectors are vectors by loading them with as.vector().  ...and yes - I'm new at R.

Is there an alternative more efficient? I also noticed that if in the smaller vector I had the same number twice, it only reported the location of the last one.  I'd like to report all of them into a separate vector.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Testing floating point numbers for equality is more often than not a bad idea. Why not include a tolerance to account for potential round-off error? Something like `which(abs(-0.3755620978 - myDBL) < 0.000001)`

Comment: Because I may be dealing with a very large random set from the normal distribution, and I want to find specific values down to the least digit available.

Comment: Once the tolerance is sufficiently small, the probability of two distinct random numbers being within that tolerance of each other is negligibly small -- so you can safely neglect it.

Comment: That's it.  I missed the tolerance part.  Thanks!  I wonder if R is doing some rounding due to the size of the larger vector, which would explain why the second answer did the same thing.  Thanks for this!

Comment: John if you post as an answer - you get the checkmark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing floating point numbers for equality is more often than not a bad idea because of round-off error. One standard solution is to include a tolerance to account such errors. Something like:

```
which(abs(-0.3755620978 - myDBL) < 0.000001)
```

The tolerance can be made smaller (or larger) to meet your needs.

Comment: I like this one because I can manipulate tolerance.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Doubles can get a little weird, as though they look the same there might be some rounding error at the smallest decimal place that makes them unequal. If I was you I'd round both my vectors to the same number of decimal places, then do the search.

```
vector1 <- round(vector1, 10)
vector2 <- round(vector2, 10)

which(vector1[1] == vector2) #Assuming you want to find the first element of vector 1
```

Without seeing the data it's hard to say for sure if this will fix things. But unless you can provide more information about how you load the 1000 element vector, and provide the data, hopefully this will work.

If this STILL doesn't work, perhaps the best bet would be to go for a level of accuracy.

```
which(vector1[1] - vector2 < 1e-10) #Assuming you want to find the first element of vector 1
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain the precision option. At some point you reach the limitation with floating point numbers. There will just be inaccuracies at the smallest decimal places. I'm not sure what the context of your problem is, but hopefully there's some level at which the similarity is good enough? The problem on matching on a whole floating point number is the number which is stored may not even be correct to the smallest decimal place, because at some point the machine has had to round! I feel adjusting precision is always the right option.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good instance to use `%in%`:

```
smallVector <- sample(1:1000, 25)
bigVector <- sample(1:1000, 2000, replace = T)

which(bigVector %in% smallVector)

 [1]    3   22   51  140  148  219  239  314  350  355  373  374  394  395  396  427  450  489  542  550
[21]  625  633  713  739  864  889  908  955 1003 1029 1071 1102 1123 1173 1198 1238 1341 1355 1376 1383
[41] 1392 1426 1429 1476 1529 1552 1574 1612 1658 1711 1721 1733 1808 1831 1902 1917 1969 1975
```

This will return an index of which items from the longer vector are in the smaller one without the need for `==`.

Comment: Would this help if both smallVector and bigVector were floats?

Comment: That one actually gave me the same problem returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to accomplish this, your best bet is to turn all numbers into strings, and do an `==` operation on string data.

That being said, as had been pointed out already, testing for equality of floating-point numbers is going to be a really bad idea. That's because floats are not printed to you in a way they are stored internally. Simple example:

```
x <- 1/9
x
[1] 0.1111111
dput(x)
0.111111111111111
x == 0.1111111
[1] FALSE
```

The `dput` command shows internal representation of data, which is different from  what your console prints to you.

Hard to say what to do instead without knowing what you seek to accomplish.